# Searching within a datetime object python

Tags: python, datetime, search, indexing

I am trying to locate where the years are within a specified bounds for a datetime object. I have tried doing a for loop a few different ways but unfortunately I cannot seem to get it to work. I know I am able to search for months and years when I convert a datetime object to a pandas array, but unfortunately the software I am using does not have the pandas library and I am unable to download it to my schools server.

Below is how I read in my time data and it works beautifully (it eliminated a lot of time it would have taken to convert my time a different way)

```
date = netCDF4.Dateset('filename.nc', mode = 'r')
raw_time = data.variables['time']
time_converted = netCDF4.num2date(raw_time[:], raw_time.units)
```

The time_converted variable is a datetime object that appears as follows:

```
   ....
   datetime.datetime(2006, 1, 1, 0, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 1, 0, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2006, 3, 1, 0, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2006, 4, 1, 0, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2006, 5, 1, 0, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2006, 6, 1, 0, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2006, 7, 1, 0, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2006, 8, 1, 0, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2006, 9, 1, 0, 0),
   .....
```

The loop below is my most recent attempt and it returns the following error:

```
time = []
for i in time_converted:
    if i.year>= 2006 and i.year<2016:
        time.append(i)

Type Error: 'int' object is not callable
```

Within my loop I have also tried using datetime.datetime.year(i) but that returns:

```
Type Error: 'getset_descriptor' is not callable
```

Comment: remove parenthesis from i.year() , it's a property not a method

Comment: @Alex when I remove the parenthesis, it returns an Index Error stating that only integers, slices, ellipsis, and 1-d integer or boolean arrays are valid indices...

Comment: could you paste the code you run? there should not be any index errors in your loop, look at stacktrace to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @Alex I updated the question to show my latest run.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use the following loop instead:

```
for i in range(len(time_converted)):
    if time_converted[i].year >= 2006 and time_converted[i].year < 2016:
        time.append(time_converted[i])
```